# compatibility of Kingston HyperX Predator kit with another Kingston kits

Tags: memory

I've got Asus Rampage V and i7 5820k and a kit Kingston HyperX Predator DDR4 2133 4x4.

With what Kingston kits my kit is compatible (with adjusting timing, voltage, frequency)? As far as I know HyperX Predator series has wide range from 2133 to 3000 -> I don't know how much I can overclock my current RAM. Also I heard Kingston FuryX is using same memory modules so theoretically those series can be used too..

Also can I use kits with 32GB (4x8) with it?

Comment: @Ramhound Done.

Comment: @Ramhound Done. If that what you meant

Comment: "I don't know how much I can overclock my current RAM" - The motherboard specifications indicate the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [ASUS Memory Qualified Vendor List (QVL)](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA2011/RAMPAGE_V_EXTREME_U31/R5E_Memory_QVL_012715.pdf) for the Rampage V Extreme.

For Kingston, the only listed memory is:

**Model:** `Kingston HX426C13PB2K4/16 16GB(4GB*4) SS` ([specifications](http://www.kingston.com/dataSheets/HX426C13PB2K4_16.pdf))

**Timings:** `13-14-14-39`

**Voltage:** `1.35V`

---

**XMP TIMING PARAMETERS**

- **JEDEC:** `DDR4-2133 CL15-15-15 @1.2V`
- **XMP Profile #1:** `DDR4-2666 CL13-14-14 @1.35V`
- **XMP Profile #2:** `DDR4-2400 CL13-13-13 @1.35V`

Comment: But it does not mean that if I used Kingston FuryX it would not work

Comment: Other memory which is not listed on the QVL may work as well.  The list from ASUS were tested and verified to work.

Comment: @user1432980 - Why are you so concerned with compatibility.  Any DDR-4 memory which runs at the same frequency as the modules you already have will work.

Comment: You mean not even Kingston?